We can't verify your phone number right now. Try again later. play console error code 400
We can't verify your phone number right now. Try again later. play console
Response code 400 

{
    "1":"9",
    "2":"Precondition Check Failed"
}

Long story short: Try verifying your email first.
I found a similar post but it's closed because it's not about software development. Software development is not about only programming. Google issue tracker has a ticket for this issue, and it says more than 4k developers have the same issue.
So I can't answer on the first post so I would post answer and question here, for developers who will try to resolve the same issue.
I resolved this issue for our account.
We had the same problem. Under the hood, during the verification request, we received a 400 server error with the message "Precondition check failed." We tried phone numbers from different countries, and attempted verification by both SMS and phone call, and nothing worked. We kept trying daily, but then I realized the email hadn't been verified. We were focused on the phone number the whole time. Once I verified the email and tried verifying the phone number again, it worked!

I'm also receiving exactly the same error, but even with the two mails validated, it's still returning this error.

Try verifying your email first.
We had the same problem. Under the hood, during the verification request, we received a 400 server error with the message "Precondition check failed." We tried phone numbers from different countries, and attempted verification by both SMS and phone call, and nothing worked. We kept trying daily, but then I realized the email hadn't been verified. We were focused on the phone number the whole time. Once I verified the email and tried verifying the phone number again, it worked!

I'm facing the same problem for almost a month now. Verifying the email address unfortunately did not help.

I solved it by changing my developer email to a different company domain email. Although the recommendation is to use the mail with the same domain of your company, which I have, the problem is that it's assumed as verified, so they never send you the mail to verify with the code.
When I changed it to a different email, they sent me the verification email, which let me continue with the payment process.
